# How to add a step to emr cluster within a vpc through lambda function which is inside a same vpc and private subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

when the lambda function is not within vpc then iam able to add a step to emr cluster but if the lambda function is residing inside vpc where emr cluster is present and same private VPC subnet also.

This time iam getting timeout error when iam trying to add a step in emr cluster using boto3 client module "add_job_flow_steps"

```
"errorMessage": "2020-05-14T02:48:46.771Z ad979ac2-ff26-476a-b301-23797caeeaa9 Task timed out after 123.10 seconds".
```

Do i need to add a VPC Endpoint for me to communicate between AWS services within same VPC Subnet or is there any other way which i could communicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when the lambda function is not within vpc then iam able to add a step to emr cluster

This works because lambda **not in vpc**, can access internet. Subsequently, you can connect to public endpoint of AWS services, such as EMR.

> if the lambda function is residing inside vpc where emr cluster is present and same private VPC subnet also.

This does not work, [because](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html) lambda in VPC **does not have internet access**:

> If your function needs internet access, use NAT. Connecting a function to a public subnet does **not give it internet access or a public IP address**.

To enable your lambda access the EMR service you need to  use either [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) or [VPC interface endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-interface.html) as shown in the following link:

- [Connect to Amazon EMR Using an Interface VPC Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/interface-vpc-endpoint.html)

Please not that lambda in VPC also requires [modified execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html#vpc-permissions).

Comment: if we have lambda and emr in the same vpc private subnet . is there any possibility of direct communication without creating vpc end point

Comment: @AbhishekDiwate You need to connect to AWS EMR service it self, which is not in your subnet. Thus you need the endpoints or nat gateway.

Comment: Hi Marcin, I'm getting this error when they are in same private subnet and same vpc .if they are in same private subnet and same vpc. VPC endpoint is not needed right??

Comment: @AbhishekDiwate I would recommend testing with VPC endpoint for EMR. If this does not help, then there maybe some other issues.